# find-file, but suppress buffer?

Tags: buffers, files

I have a function that opens a buffer in order to extract some information from it, then switches back to the original buffer and inserts some text:

```
(save-excursion 
  (find-file ThisFile)
  (setq results some-function))
(insert results)
```

The brief flash when emacs switches to the new buffer is disconcerting. Is it possible to suppress the buffer -- I guess, keep it at the bottom of the buffer stack?

Comment: You probably need `find-file-noselect` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Find-a-File.html

Comment: See also `with-temp-buffer` http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html and `insert-file-contents` http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-from-Files.html

Comment: @kaushalmodi I tried this, but then the subsequent operations in the save-excursion block get carried out on the original buffer (from which to command is called), sort of defeating the purpose.

Comment: @lawlist that works!  I'll rewrite as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked.  As to the other idea with `find-file-noselect` in the first comment, a common usage is in conjunction with the macro `with-current-buffer` -- but then the buffer either says around or needs to be killed.  `insert-file-contents` won't automatically enable a major-mode, whereas `find-file-noselect` may trigger a major-mode.  It just depends upon personal preference and the result desired.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @lawlist for this answer.

Instead of

```
(save-excursion
   (find-file some-file)
   ... )
```

the solution is to use

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents some-file)
  ... )
```

This keeps the temp buffer in the background, and also eliminates the problem of stray buffers being left behind after the operation is complete.  Works perfectly!

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had a problem with visual-bell. Try this for gui Emacs:

```
(setq visible-bell nil)
```

or this for terminal Emacs

```
(setq visible-bell t)
```

One of these will fix it.

Comment: This had no effect for me.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you. I got that hint from someone else here on SX and it fixed the flicker for me.